# How to use OpenRAVE's IK with a 5DoF manipulator?

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ik, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After successfully converting my URDF file to COLLADA, I can start the IK service like this:

```
roscd katana_description/collada
rosrun orrosplanning ik_openrave.py --scene="katana6m90a.robot.xml"
```

The files to reproduce have been added to the [katana_description](http://www.ros.org/wiki/katana_description) package.

Now, when I make a call to the `GetPositionIK` service (the ROS version, of type `kinematics_msgs/GetPositionIK`), I get the following error message:

```
...
ValueError: number of joints to solve for is not equal to required joints 5!=6
```

Of course, it is impossible to solve 6DoF IK with a 5DoF arm. Is it possible to use one of the other IK types that OpenRAVE offers to move my gripper into a grasping position?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9898/how-to-use-openrave%27s-ik-with-a-5dof-manipulator?/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Excellent question. 5D IK support is new, so thanks for warning us about it. Just added it (jsk-ros-pkg r1300)

First, you should use the orrosplanning/IK service which gives you the ability to select the ik type. The GetPositionIK service is just there for compatibility reasons with the commonly used ROS manipulation. messages.

The orrosplanning/test/testarmik.py will show you how to call the IK service.

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1